# Check if a cell has string data when doing pandas iterrow

Tags: python, pandas, string, loops, if-statement

I'm using iterrows in a dataframe like below to get the time difference

```
       ImageA_Time            ImageB_Time
0      2022-02-01 06:56:22    2022-02-02 06:56:22
1      No time info           2022-02-02 06:57:22
2      No time info           2022-02-02 06:57:22
```

I want to add a column called 'Time Delta' showing the time difference of ImageA and ImageB for each row. Here is the desired output:

```
       ImageA_Time            ImageB_Time             Time_Delta
0      2022-02-01 06:56:22    2022-02-02 06:56:22     24h
1      No time info           2022-02-02 06:57:22     Nan
2      No time info           2022-02-02 06:57:22     Nan
```

My question is how to write if sentence here when doing iterrow? Below is my idea but it still shows

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'Timestamp'

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['ImageA_Time'] is str:
        df['Time_Delta'] = 'Nan'
    else:
        df['Time_Delta'] = row['ImageA_Time'] - row['ImageB_Time']
```

Comment: `if isinstance (row['ImageA_Time'], str):`

Comment: `is` means `is exactly same`, your content is NOT the "type str itself"

Comment: For the "if" line you want `if isinstance(row['ImageA_Time'], str):`

Comment: Thank you! I forgot this one isinstance()